# Remove double escape characters from a string and make it a binary

Tags: string, python-3.x, binary

I have a string looking like this:

`"\\xd6\\x83\\x8dd!VT\\x92\\xaaA\\x05\\xe0\\x9b\\x8b\\xf1"`

and I want to remove the double escape characters in order to make it a proper binary. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source string looks pretty much like a `bytes` string, so you could do:

```py
>>> import ast
>>> s = "\\xd6\\x83\\x8dd!VT\\x92\\xaaA\\x05\\xe0\\x9b\\x8b\\xf1"
>>> print(ast.literal_eval("b'''%s'''" % s))
b'\xd6\x83\x8dd!VT\x92\xaaA\x05\xe0\x9b\x8b\xf1'
```